# dropdown menu dosnt close on mobile (works fine on desktop) - superfish.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, superfish

Im using the superfish.js dropdown menu plugin for a dropdown menu, it works fine on desktop but on touch devices if a user touches the triggering icon the nav will open and just stay open, ive been looking at various JS to try and get the sub menu to close automatically after 5 seconds, but to no avail, any idea how i could do this ?

Ive created a js fiddle of the issue here : https://jsfiddle.net/6nupavet/

I wasnt able to use the external resource tool in JSfiddle so ive had to load the content of external files : `superfish.js` + `hover-intent.js` + `superfish.css` inside of the editor. Custom css + initialising js is below these scripts.

Answer (score 0):

try to add this and check it out

```
 var track = function(ev){cursor: "pointer"})
.on('click', function(){
  $(this).find('ul').toggle();
 };
```

Comment: Thanks, i added it to the fiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/6nupavet/1/ - but unfortunatly it dosnt seem to solve the issue, ive found i can emulate the issue using Chrome's device mode emulator